# Partial vs complete match ranking in postgresql text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to implement incremental search using PostgreSQL. The problem I am running into is result ranking. I would like complete matches to be ranked higher than partial matches and I don't really know how to do that. For example in this query (to show how things are ranked as the user types the query):

```
select
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jonathan'), to_tsquery('jon:*')),
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jonathan'), to_tsquery('jonath:*')),
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jonathan'), to_tsquery('jonathan:*'))
```

or the other way around (to show how different documents rank the same query)

```
select
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jon'), to_tsquery('jon:*')),
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jonah'), to_tsquery('jon:*')),
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('hello jonathan'), to_tsquery('jon:*'))
```

all rankings return 0.1. How would I go about making more complete results rank higher?

Comment: Why are you ranking different queries, rather than the different vectors?  In incremental searching, wouldn't the query be a single given at any one moment?

Comment: The vector is the same, because my data is the same. The query is different because the user keeps typing more letters.

Comment: Your data consists of a single row?  Again, at any given time, they have typed one particular number of letters.  Why are you ranking the queries from different times against each other?  What is that supposed to achieve?  If this is really what you want to achieve, just sort them by length.

Comment: The reason I gave this specific example is to illustrate the problem I have. I want more complete matches ranked higher. And no, this is not the query I will use, but posting the actual code does not illustrate the problem. Basically, when user types "jon" I want "Jon" ranked higher than "Jonah" and "Jonah" ranked higher than "Jonathan".

Comment: Updated my question with another example

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an operator from [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) to break ties among the ts_rank_cd.  Probably the "<->>>" operator (introduced in v11) would be my first choice:

```
select
    'hello jon' <->>>  'jon:*',
    'hello jonah' <->>> 'jon:*',
    'hello jonathan'<->>>'jon:*';
 ?column? |  ?column?  | ?column? 
----------+------------+----------
        0 | 0.57142854 |      0.7
```

Note that this returns distance, not similarity, so lower is better.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with 9.4